# Convert excel into CSV and save

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert the xls file into csv file and tried to save it using powershell command, but I am getting error:

```
"'$excelApp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'$excelApp.DisplayAlerts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'$workbook' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'$csvFilePath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'$workbook.SaveAs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'$workbook.Close' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
```

Comment: This is the code I tried

Comment: set dir_Home=D:\592737\NRT\R2F\1903

for %%F in ("%dir_Home%\*.xlsx") do (
@echo In for loop
$excelApp = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
    $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false 

$workbook = $excelApp.Workbooks.Open(%%F.FullName) 
        $csvFilePath = %%F.FullName -replace "\.xlsx$", ".csv" 
        $workbook.SaveAs($csvFilePath, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlCSV) 
        $workbook.Close() 
                                
                                


)
pause

Comment: Code doesn't work in comments as it gets mashed into a single line, instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54626833/edit) your question and include it there (with correct formatting!)

Comment: Are you running this in a powershell console? It looks like a `.bat` file to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
###################################################################################
### The following is a function to convert XLSX format to CSV Format
### To execute the script --> Get-ExcelData -path "Path of the XLSX sheet"
###################################################################################

function Get-ExcelData {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Worksheet')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [String] $Path,

        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName='Worksheet')]
        [String] $WorksheetName = 'Sheet1',

        [Parameter(Position=1, ParameterSetName='Query')]
        [String] $Query = 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'
    )

    switch ($pscmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'Worksheet' {
            $Query = 'SELECT * FROM [{0}$]' -f $WorksheetName
            break
        }
        'Query' {
            # Make sure the query is in the correct syntax (e.g. 'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
            $Pattern = '.*from\b\s*(?<Table>\w+).*'
            if($Query -match $Pattern) {
                $Query = $Query -replace $Matches.Table, ('[{0}$]' -f $Matches.Table)
            }
        }
    }

    # Create the scriptblock to run in a job
    $JobCode = {
        Param($Path, $Query)

        # Check if the file is XLS or XLSX 
        if ((Get-Item -Path $Path).Extension -eq 'xls') {
            $Provider = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'
            $ExtendedProperties = 'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'
        } else {
            $Provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'
            $ExtendedProperties = 'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'
        }

        # Build the connection string and connection object
        $ConnectionString = 'Provider={0};Data Source={1};Extended Properties="{2}"' -f $Provider, $Path, $ExtendedProperties
        $Connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $ConnectionString

        try {
            # Open the connection to the file, and fill the datatable
            $Connection.Open()
            $Adapter = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter $Query, $Connection
            $DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
            $Adapter.Fill($DataTable) | Out-Null
        }
        catch {
            # something went wrong ??
            Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
        }
        finally {
            # Close the connection
            if ($Connection.State -eq 'Open') {
                $Connection.Close()
            }
        }

        # Return the results as an array
        return ,$DataTable
    }

    # Run the code in a 32bit job, since the provider is 32bit only
    $job = Start-Job $JobCode -RunAs32 -ArgumentList $Path, $Query
    $job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
    Remove-Job $job
}
```

To execute the script -

```
Get-ExcelData -path \\PathToYourExcelSheet\ExcelSheet.xlsx
```

The above code would convert xlsx to csv one at a time.